# Facing issue in deploying guvnor.war in tomcat 7.0.30

Tags: tomcat7, drools-guvnor

How do I deploy the guvnor.war (Version 5.4.0.Final) in Tomcat 7.0.30 server? Its giving me the following error:

> **Type**: Exception report
>
> **Message**
>
> **Description**: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> **Exception**
>
> ```
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   org.jboss.seam.transaction.TransactionServletListener.requestInitialized(TransactionServletListener.java:106)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
> ```
>
> Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/7.0.30 logs.

Answer (score 19):

The following resolved the above issue for me. I have `TomCat 7.0.34` installed with `5.4.0 Final of Guvnor`.

You can disable the seam transaction listener by adding appropriate `<context-param>` to the `web.xml` file that you should find in

```
[tomcat-dir]\webapps\[nameOfGuvnorJar]\WEB-INF\
```

where `[tomcat-dir]` is your top level directory path to where you have installed `Tomcat`.
and `[nameOfGuvnorJar]` is the name you gave to the guvnor application that you have deployed in `Tomcat`.

The lines required are

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>org.jboss.seam.transaction.disableListener</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

It needs to be added inside the `<web-app>` element

You will probably need to restart the webserver for the change to be picked up.

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem. By the way, no need to restart the server if Guvnor is deployed in vfabric-tc-server-developer-X.X.X.RELEASE/base-instance/webapps.